# Replacing the end of the line by SED in makefile

Tags: ubuntu, sed, append

**How can you append to the end of a line by SED controlled by makefile?**

I run

```
paste -d" " t.tex tE.tex | sed 's@$@XXX@' > tM.tex
```

where the problem is in the use of the mark `$` for the end of the line.

I get

```
#paste -d" " t.tex tE.tex | sed -e s/" "/\\\&/g | sed -r "s/XXX/" > tM.tex
sed: -e expression #1, char 10: unterminated `s' command
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

I have the command just after the "all:" tag in my makefile which contains only the two lines.

The parameters `-n` and `-e` do not help here.
The command works as expected run when it is run directly in terminal.

Comment: Can you add some sample inputs and your expected outputs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$` character is a special character in Makefiles. To get a literal `$` in a command you need to quote it by prefixing it with another one: `$$`. For more information, see [6.1 Basics of Variable References](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Reference) in the GNU make manual.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the final "/" from the last sed command.

```
  paste -d" " t.tex tE.tex | sed s/" "/\\\&/g | sed -r "s/XXX//" > tM.tex
```

this works fine for me on linux, however this does not contain the $ char your problem mentions